# How to extract month in double digit format from date column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract month in the form of double digits from my database table in SQL Server.

```
SELECT 
   Cast(datepart(month, prod_date) as nvarchar(10))
FROM myTbl
```

what I got:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

what I need:

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12
```

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`convert()` the date to string with style 101, it will gives you `MM/DD/YYYY`. using `char(2)` will truncate off the rest and leave the 2 digits month

```
select  convert(char(2), prod_date, 101)
from    myTbl
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution +1.

Comment: it is a `cheat` :)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT FORMAT(prod_date, 'MM')
FROM myTbl;
```

[Format Function Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a padding trick with `RIGHT` here:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(month, prod_date) AS nvarvhar(10)), 2)
FROM myTbl;
```

The idea is to prepend a `0` to every month number string, and then retain only the right two digits, which would be either a two digit month already, or a single digit with a zero in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try MySql DATE_FORMAT() Function to extract month in the form of double digits

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(prod_date, '%m') FROM myTbl
```

Comment: This question is not related to the MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

try this

replicate 0 for length-1 and concatinate

```
select replicate('0',2-len(datepart(month, prod_date)))+cast(datepart(month, prod_date) as nvarchar(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a minor improvement to your query as answer you can also do the same as shown below.

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('00'+
          Cast(datepart(month, prod_date) as Varchar(10))
         , 2)
FROM myTbl
```

Here is an example below.

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('00'+
          Cast(datepart(month, '2019-1-1') as Varchar(10))
         , 2) as MonthInTwoDigit
```

The output of the above query is:

```
MonthInTwoDigit
---------------
    01
---------------
```

Another way of doing is the shown below using `month()` function.

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('00'+
              Convert(Varchar(2), Month(prod_date))
          ,2) as MonthInTwoDigit
from myTbl
```